# ¿por qué no se crea las tablas en la base de datos de h2?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, spring-boot, maven, h2

cree la entidad usuario como primera tabla de mi base de datos

```
@Entity
public class Usuario {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String contrasena;
    
}
```

tengo esta configuración H2

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:file:C:/escolar/data/bd
spring.datasource.driverClassName= org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
```

cuando lo inicio no me crea la tabla usuario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he creado otras tablas y relacionas entre ellas, aunque de igual manera siguen sin aparecer.
que puedo hacer para resolver este problema, gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score -1):

logre solucionar de esa manera
info en link
https://refactorizando.com/base-de-datos-memoria-h2-spring-boot/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por qué esta respuesta soluciona la pregunta? Qué hay de diferente en esa configuración que propones? Los enlaces externos no son buena idea; si el sitio cambia o muere, el enlace se rompe y la respuesta no sirve para nada.